# Adding Sysdate to Datafile using Shell scripting

Tags: sh

How to add sysdate to datafile name in shell scripting .

Ex : AAb.csv

Print like below

AAb7192017.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
echo 'AAB`date +%m%d%Y`.csv'
```

If filename is stored in a variable then use,

```
echo ${VAR/./`date +%m%d%Y`.}
```